# X-axis labels not showing on bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm having an issue with my plot only displaying every other label on the x-axis.

Code:

```
m_count=  [12, 12, 13, 16, 12, 12, 13, 16, 9, 10]
f_count =[13, 13, 12, 9, 13, 13, 11, 9, 15, 15]
    
labels = ["Capomulin", "Ceftamin", "Infubinol", "Ketapril", "Naftisol", "Placebo", "Propriva", "Ramicane", "Stelasyn", "Zoniferol"]
N=10
ind = np.arange(N)
width = .35
fig= plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.bar(ind, m_count, width, color ="b")
ax.bar(ind, f_count, width, color ="r", bottom=m_count)
ax.set_ylabel('Count')
ax.set_title("Count of Mice by Drug Regimen")
ax.set_xticks(ind, labels)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90 )
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 30, 2))
ax.legend(labels=['Male', 'Female'])
plt.show()
```

This results in :

[image]

Comment: `ax.set_xticks(ind, labels)` should result in `TypeError: set_ticks() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`, because it doesn't take `labels`. Update to the current version of matplotlib (3.4.3), and use `ax.set_xticks(ind)`, which should resolve the issue. [Code and Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvUoN.png). I'm voting to close the as caused by a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My quickest fix is to use

```
plt.xticks(ind, labels)
```

But thanks to Trenton's comments, I have come up with an updated solution:

```
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Comment: That worked! Thought for sure I'd tried a plt variation.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks, great to know, please see updated version!

Comment: That's a more appropriate answer. Just as an FYI, this type of issue, is usually considered a typo, and there's a specific close vote. Issues caused by typos aren't typically beneficial to the community, so those questions are usually closed and deleted.